# Programmatically how to create task scheduler in windows server 2008

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, c#-2.0, user-input, using

The task scheduler which works fine when running my application in Windows Xp because task file is saved as .job. But in windows server 2008 the task scheduler file is saving in XML format. How to get the Task scheduler in Xml format?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Task Scheduler API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx or use Schtasks.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357.aspx